# What's the Boost test framework's equivalence of std::cout?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I understand that in my unit test I should do

```
BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("message");
```

instead of

```
std::cout << "message";
```

but what if for a function that's expecting `std::ostream&` ?

so instead of

```
hexdump(std::cout, buffer, length);
```

what should I replace `std::cout` with?

Comment: maybe covert it to somthing other than std::ostrwam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the `hexdump` function you can pass in a `std::ostringstream` instead.

[Here](http://drdobbs.com/184403775) and [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/streamstrings.html) are a few more examples of how to use it.